# Would it be accepted to have a "cops and robbers" thread with only one side?

Tags: discussion, cops-and-robbers

I would like to mainly give myself programming challenges by basically asking multiple times to break my previous code. This would be like the "cops and robbers" format on PP&CG, only that **I** would be the only contributor on the "cops" side.

Should I...

- ... create no "cops" thread?
- ... create a "cops" thread, but put in its description that I don't want answers from anyone there?
- Or is not wanted to have such a challenge here?

Also, maybe at some point I don't have new ideas to secure my code any more. Could I then just make a real "cops" thread/open it for anyone?

Comment: Why not allow others to post similar challenges (ie Cops)?

Comment: What do you mean? For easier communication: Code securing=cops side, code breaking=robbers side. I want to be the one securing the code, because I want to get programming challenges for me. And no, the solution would not be to just look through the PP&CG feed, because I want a specific type of challenge, people should make the same thing harder and harder for me.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to restrict the challenge in that way. Cops and Robbers are fun because it is a constant back and forth. If you only allow yourself to post on the cops side, that would be a lot less 'back and forth'y. Keep in mind that when your code would get broken, there is nothing to do on the challenge until you would post a new version.

Comment: Does it really hurt you if others were to post challenges simultaneously?

Comment: I guess not too much for my own programming, I could just not read them before I come up with my own solution. But wouldn't the rules of C&R say that their solution is the next challenge for the robbers, not mine?

Comment: Depends on what the challenge is. In some of the recent CnR challenges anyone could post in the cops thread, and anyone could try and solve them. No real restrictions for whose turn it is or anything.

Comment: [example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135363/59530), [example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread)

Comment: The two examples were ones where all challenge answers were independent from cracking answers. My case would have a clear order. Do you think I can convert my case into something like that? If yes, how would I do it best?

Comment: Why don't you post your idea's in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1), this way it is easier to see what your intentions are, and how this can be fit into the format.

Comment: Ok, I'll do later today.

Comment: BTW there is the [tag:tips] tag.

Comment: "Later today" became a day later, but now I'll do. But another question first: Do you think it would be good to have a tree-like structure of the challenge? So that multiple people could solve one challenge and each answer would be a starting point for again multiple answers to that. That might be good, but it might also lead to many questions staying unanswered.